# Can not gradle build project when i add ChatInformation kotlin class that extends RealmObject to my project, where is error?

Tags: android, realm, kotlin, realm-mobile-platform

This is my ChatInformation kotlin class:

```
open class ChatInformation(
    var Id: Int = 0,
    var TopicId: Int = 0,
    var CreateTime: String? = null,
    var StartTime: String? = null,
    var EndTime: String? = null,
    var StatusId: Int = 0,
    var Duration: String? = null,
    var TeacherId: String = "",
    var LearnerId: String = "",
    var SubjectName: String = "",
    var TopicTitle: String = "",
    var Class: Int = 0,
    var Learner: String = "",
    var Teacher: String = "",
    var TeacherReady: Boolean = false,
    var LearnerReady: Boolean = false
) : RealmObject()
```

if i add this class i get following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

if see compliler this

```
Note: Processing class ChatLesson
Note: Processing class CustomMessage
Note: Processing class RequestListen
Note: Creating DefaultRealmModule
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_152-release). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

with long error trace

if i delete or comment ChatInformation class builds successfully where is error?
I have tried in both realm 3.5.0 and 3.7.1 versions

Answer (score 1):

My error was that: i have a

> var Class: Int = 0

field in my ChatInformation class if remove this field it works nice